# Unable to retrieve yahoo email using lightopenid

Tags: php, openid, lightopenid

I am trying to incorporate openid authentication using LightOpenID. i modified the discovery url in example-google.php for integrating with yahoo! but i am not getting any attributes (i am at least able to fetch the email id with google.).

http://pastebin.com/08RzvsGy

Comment: I've copy-pasted your code, tested it, and it works. What version of the library do you use?

Comment: Can this question be marked as solved?

Answer (score 0):

Just for any others searching night and day for the simple answer of retrieving a email address returned from lightopenid.  THANKS FOR POSTING YOUR CODE.  IT HELPED.  In case others don't click your link.  here is the code from your page above that allows for the transfer of email addresses.

```
$openid->required = array('contact/email');

// optional data
$openid->optional = array('namePerson','namePerson/friendly','birthDate','person/gender');
```